# Call a function in Controller from javascript file

Tags: c#, javascript, html, model-view-controller, controller

Call function of Controller in javascript js file.

I know that there are some questions relating to this, but I haven't found any appropriate one, so I want create this topic.

I have one controller and the function which returns a string based on the input of the parameter from Html file.

Example of Controller:

```
 public class UtilsController : BaseController
{
//
// GET: /Utils/

public string testTranslation(string inputDictKey)
{

    switch (inputDictKey)
    {
        case "reference":
            return "réf";
        case "country":
            return "pays";
    }
    return "test_translation_null";
}


public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Websites/Index.cshtml");
}
```

}

and in the HTML file, I want that each time the html file is rendered, there is a js function that send the input text to the testTranslation Controller MVC and then return a correct string.

```
<div id="getKeyDict">
    <strong>
        <span id="display_key" data-bind="text:key" />
    </strong>
</div>
```

The data-bind is the value which will be rendered, and that is the parameter that I want to send to the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var url = "@Url.Action("Utils", "testTranslation")",
            $displ = $("#display_key"),
            dataObj = {
                inputDictKey: $displ.data("bind")
            };
        $.get(url, dataObj, function(result){
            $displ.html(result);
        });
    });
</script>
```